# Word Index - numbers as words

Tags: vba, indexing, ms-word

Is it possible to have index terms filed under the spelled out number, rather than the arabic numeral? For example, I have a term "2,4-D" which appears under a index header of "2" instead of "T" i.e. "two." I have tried changing the wdIndexSortBy option from wdIndexSortByStroke to wdIndexSortBySyllable, but it doesn't appear to have any effect. I can't find anything else that seems close.

Comment: I don't think this is possible. You can spell out the numbers in your index entry {XE "Two, Four-D"}, but this will mean that the term is spelled out in the index. Depending on your workflow, perhaps you could use that functionality to get them in the right place, and then change the words back to numbers after unlinking your Index field. That might not be any easier than just moving the numbered terms, though.

Comment: Yeah, I don't think it is possible. I ended up using a sub entry so there is an entry for "TWO" with an indented sub entry for "2, 4-D" which isn't all that pretty, but passable. Thanks for your input, Christina.